# GRanges coverage error with discordant reads

Tags: bioconductor, bowtie2

I mapped my fastq files from 4SU-seq experiment to human genome hg19 with bowtie 2 and got this results:

```
    67716784 reads; of these:
  67716784 (100.00%) were paired; of these:
    29941143 (44.22%) aligned concordantly 0 times
    33244334 (49.09%) aligned concordantly exactly 1 time
    4531307 (6.69%) aligned concordantly >1 times
    ----
    29941143 pairs aligned concordantly 0 times; of these:
      9287621 (31.02%) aligned discordantly 1 time
    ----
    20653522 pairs aligned 0 times concordantly or discordantly; of these:
      41307044 mates make up the pairs; of these:
        32859156 (79.55%) aligned 0 times
        3142531 (7.61%) aligned exactly 1 time
        5305357 (12.84%) aligned >1 times
75.74% overall alignment rate
```

I also ran a second mapping with --no-discordant and --no-mixed. After that I read the bam files into R like this:

```
x1 <- BamFile(paste0(bam.path, "14751.OnlyConcordantReads.sorted.bam"), asMates = T)
x2 <- BamFile(paste0(bam.path, "14751.AllReads.sorted.bam"), asMates = T)
x1 <- readGAlignmentPairs(x1)
x2 <- readGAlignmentPairs(x2)
x1_gr <- granges(x1, use.names=T)
x2_gr <- granges(x2,use.names=T, on.discordant.seqnames="drop")
```

The parameter on.discordant.seqnames is necessary, otherwise an error occurs.

```
z <- GRanges("chr1",IRanges(236958581,237067281))
xcov <- coverage(x1_gr)
xnum <- as.numeric(xcov$chr1[ranges(z)])
plot(xnum)
ycov <- coverage(x2_gr)
ynum <- as.numeric(ycov$chr1[ranges(z)])
plot(ynum)
```

I get very unusual coverage values (all summed up to 154 - see image) when I use on.discordant.seqnames="drop". Why is that?

[image: normal]

[image: on.discordant.seqnames="drop"]

In addition, the coverage does not match my bed files.